# Finding cycles in a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, dictionary, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I have a python dictionary of ids. Each id has a set of other ids to which it references. How can I find circular references within the dictionary?

An example of my dictionary is:

```
{1: [3], 2: [1], 3: [2, 4], 4: [2, 3]}.
```

The value of each id key is a list of the other ids it references and they can't reference themselves.

So the output, if there were a circular reference, would be:

```
{3, 4 , 3}.
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to go about this as it seems like it would be a common problem! Thank you very much for anyone that helps.

Comment: This is not "circular reference" because those are not references, those are some ids. You'll have better luck finding it in graph algorithms - what your dict describes is basically a directed graph ("graph with arrows") and you want a directed cycle.

Comment: @h4z3 I am not sure OP wants a directed cycle because `1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1` is a directed cycle that is not mentioned in the output? OP - please confirm

Comment: @Mortz Because OP wants "circular references", it would mean they only want a "direction" the dict is in, so directed cycle. But you're right that their example is lacking - do they want any cycle? Shortest? I just dumped info how to find solutions, without analysing it much, so I didn't notice that other cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Apologies for the poorly organised question (it's my first post). I was looking to find all the occurrences of cycles, I just had no pen and paper (or sleep) to conceptualise what all the outputs would be, simple as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `networkx` library can find cycles in your graph.  You will need to instantiate a directed graph, because your links between IDs are one-way.  You have multiple cycles in your graph.  For instance, 3 goes to 4 and 4 goes to 3.  That is also considered a cycle.

```py
import networkx as nx

data = {1: [3], 2: [1], 3: [2, 4], 4: [2, 3]}
graph = nx.DiGraph(data)

list(nx.simple_cycles(graph))
# returns:
[[1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 3, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'd gotten confuddled about trying to write something myself!

Comment: Please remember to vote for useful answers and click the check mark if a response fully answers your question

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for circular references of length only 2, i.e. only for pairs (i,j) such that i references j and j references i, then the code below works:

```
d = {1: [3], 2: [1], 3: [2, 4], 4: [2, 3]}

for i in d:
    for j in d[i]:
        if i in d[j]:
            print("Cycle found: ", i, j)
```

Output:

```
Cycle found:  3 4
Cycle found:  4 3
```

The program above does the following: for each key i in the dictionary, if i references j, then check whether j also references i (i.e. whether i is also in d[j]), and if so, print i and j.  You can augment the program to store (or print) (i,j) only if i < j, in order to not print each cycle twice.

If you want to also print circular references of larger lengths (such as when i references j, j references k, and k references i), then you can construct a directed graph with edge set {(i,j): i references j}, and run an algorithm (such as [Johnson's algorithm)](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0204007) to find all elementary cycles in a digraph.